# Jenkins screen session will killed after pipeline finish

Tags: session, jenkins, deployment, gnu-screen

Im currently working on a deployment process that is working fine until the last stage.
I have Jenkins installed on my debian 10 machine. I have a git project with a Jenkinsfile inside.
All stages are working fine.

My problem is now, that I want to start a session with Jenkins with the screen command, the session is now created (detached) and after that the pipeline will finish, the session doesnt exist anymore.

To create the session I use the following commands:

```
screen -S server ./start.sh
```

-> That will tell me: Must be connected to a terminal.

Then I tried this command:

```
screen -dm -S server ./start.sh
```

-> Here the session will be created and then removed after Jenkins is finish with the pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following solution that is working fine for me:

```
sh 'JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontKillMe ./start.sh'
```

That will run my bash script with the screen command